# Scheduled Task null value return from sqlcmd in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, sqlcmd

I have a PowerShell script which is running a SQL query from a Windows Server 2008R2 Server; when logged on to the Server with a domain Administrator/ Service Account the script runs and completes from both basic PS and ISE. If I schedule the same script using the same Administrator/ Service Account from Task Scheduler the query does not return any value. The scheduled task is running as ‘Run with Highest Privileges.’ PowerShell is V4.

```
$Result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance Server -Database Database -Query $Query
```

Where run manually `$Result` always returns a value and yet from the Scheduled Task `$Result` is always null. In both instances the remainder of the script runs successfully and completes.

Comment: trap your error output into a file and update your question with the error.  My initial thoughts is that this is user session related, you might need to use a credentialed session.

Comment: From the sounds of it it does not appear to be failing so I don't think there is an error to capture. Unless the `$ErrorActionPreference` has been set in this script which would be useful to know. Perhaps just not returning anything? Maybe in how `$query` is being generated.... I don't know for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, as a rule whilst initially developing a script I add an 
Add-Content $Location $Variable
line under every possible action to ensure I can follow the logic through in a text file it’s very useful and in this case for me running manually I ‘see’ an output against the variables in question however the schedule task returns a blank.

Comment: I have run with Start-Transcript and the error recorded is: Transcript started, output file is d:\Logs\Debug.out
Invoke-Sqlcmd : The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
sqlcmd runs from cmd and invoke-sqlcmd runs perfectly well from PS and ISE ... just not when scheduled.

Comment: Is the SQL snapin/module loaded when running as scheduled task?
Is `Add-Snapin` part of your script, or is it loaded automagically when using the console/ISE (e.g. via [Profile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/2008.10.windowspowershell.aspx))? Is this 32/64bit PowerShell? [Invoke-SqlCmd how-to](http://www.jasonq.com/blog/2012/3-things-to-do-if-invoke-sqlcmd-is-not-recognized-in-windows-powershell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s the ‘resolution’ although it really feels like a cheat. I attempted different trigger methods to start the script; first a .bat file which also maddeningly ran when manually started but also failed when scheduled. Next I wrote a simple .vbs script to start the PowerShell script which worked when run manually and this, at least, did run correctly from scheduler … I can’t explain it …

Answer (score 0):

Literally faced this today.
The result from this query is of the type `System.Data.Datarow`. I'm guessing you are just entering `$Result` in the console/ISE?
PowerShell is being nice and doing an on-the-fly conversion.

Try `Write-Host "$Result"` and you should see `System.Data.Datarow` instead of your results.

The question then becomes where to convert this `System.Data.Datarow` to. This really depends on the rest of your code (and isn't my strong point). Lazy examples below.

```
$Results | Out-file ".\Results.txt"
$csv = ConvertTo-Csv $Results
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, I know the query returns two columns in the result and my next line is $Col1  = $Result.Col1 and so on which is populated when I run manually and blank when scheduled.

Comment: Happy to help. Hmm I see; I expected the scheduled run to also return $Results but in a different form (my anologues $Result.Col1 is not blank)
Commented above regarding Invoke-Sqlcmd error.